# StageWebView, iOS, cross-origin requests

Tags: javascript, ios, apache-flex, flash-builder, stagewebview

I have a mobile app built with Flash Builder 4.7, targeting iOS.  I'm using StageWebView to display html/Javascript content that's built into the app.  I have an in-app HTTP server that serves the html/Javascript content to the StageWebView.

html/Javascript content makes HTTPS requests to our remote server.  Because I am using an in-app server, the server sees the origin for these requests as coming from localhost.  And it's a different port number each time.

Is there a way to specify what the origin string should be for these requests, instead of letting StageWebView/iOS determine it?